# resize image base on width, height condition using python

Tags: python, image-processing

Heere is my specs

```
The extension .jpg/.png for Image is required to proper display
‐ The dimension of Landscape image max-width: 1618px, if smaller keep the
original
‐ The dimension of Portrait image max-height: 920px, if smaller keep the original
‐ Full path to server of img_path is required
‐ File name of image original starts with prefix “original”. The file name should be
original_imagename.
```

Here what I have tried:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

yourpath = os.getcwd()
ext = ['.tiff','.tif']
size = (1618,920)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[1].lower() in ext:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".jpg"):
                print "A jpeg file already exists for %s" % name
            # If a jpeg is *NOT* present, create one from the tiff.
            else:
                outfile = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".jpg"
                try:
                    im = Image.open(os.path.join(root, name))#open image file
                    width = im.size[0]
                    height = im.size[1]

                    print "Generating jpeg for %s " % name
                    if width >= 1618 and height>=920:
                        #resize the image 
                        im.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
                        im.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=100)
                    else: 
                        im.resize(im.size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
                        im.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=100)
                except Exception, e:
                    print e
```

What the problem with my image resize code, because I always get the re-sized image as the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [first link on google](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.resize):

> resize #
>
> im.resize(size) ⇒ image
>
> im.resize(size, filter) ⇒ image
>
> Returns a resized copy of an image.

The function `resize` returns a new image, so you should use it like this:

```
resized_image=im.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
resized_image.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=100)
```